# Best practices for handling binary data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What are the best practices for reading and writing binary data in Ruby?

In the code sample below I needed to send a binary file using over HTTP (as POST data):

```
class SimpleHandler < Mongrel::HttpHandler
  def process(request, response)
    response.start(200) do |head,out|
      head["Content-Type"] = "application/ocsp-responder"
      f = File.new("resp.der", "r")
      begin
        while true
          out.syswrite(f.sysread(1))
        end
      rescue EOFError => err
        puts "Sent response."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

While this code seems to do a good job, it probably isn't very idiomatic. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then [FileUtils](http://github.com/nahi/httpclient) copy_stream might be of use.

```
require 'fileutils'
fin = File.new('svarttag.jpg')
fout = File.new('blacktrain.jpg','w')
FileUtils.copy_stream(fin,fout)
fin.close
fout.close
```

<strike>Maybe not exactly what you asked for but if it's the whole HTTP POST files issue you want to solve then [HTTPClient](http://github.com/nahi/httpclient) can do it for you:</strike>

```
require 'httpclient'    
HTTPClient.post 'http://nl.netlog.com/test', { :file => File.new('resp.der') }
```

Also I've heard that Nick Siegers [multipart-post](http://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post) is good but I haven't used it.

Comment: I added some extra context to the sample code. As you can see I have to use the IO object provided by the Mongrel framwork, so I can't just use a HTTPClient.post instead.

Comment: When opening binary files you should always add the "binary" modifier (`b`) to the filemode. So, above you should have `File.new('svarttag.jpg', 'rb')` and `File.new('blacktrain.jpg', 'wb')`.